# Ruby 1.9 Kernel::system not working on Windows

Tags: ruby, windows-7

I use `system "java -cp xxx.jar"` in my ruby script and it runs well on Mac OS.  But when I run the script on Windows 7 x64, those `java -cp xxx.jar` did not get executed and no error was reported.

Answer (score 1):

`system` doesn't throw an exception or anything if your command fails to run (which may be why you said "no error was reported").

So, you need to check whether `java` is in your `PATH`; by default on Windows, it's not, and you need to add the JDK's `bin` directory to your `PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

Also your script can not be executed if you use several java classes in the classpath with ":"(colon) instead of ";"(semicolon) in Windows case;

`classpath_separator = RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /mswin/ ? ';' : ':'`

And if you want to catch output of the system command you can use next code:

```
def run_cmd cmd, cmd_name = 'Command'
# save current STDOUT reference
default_stdout = STDOUT.dup
# temp file used to capture output of the child processes
# and avoid conflicts between several processes running at the same time
# (temp file has a unique name and will be cleaned after close)
tmp_file = Tempfile.new 'tmp'

cmd_output = ''
puts "Begin #{cmd_name}: #{cmd}"
begin
  # redirect default STDOUT to the tempfile
  $stdout.reopen tmp_file
  # execute command
  system "#{cmd} 2>&1"
ensure
  # read temp file content
  tmp_file.rewind
  cmd_output = tmp_file.read
  tmp_file.close
  # restore default STDOUT
  $stdout.reopen default_stdout
end

# push output to console
puts "Output of #{cmd_name}: #{cmd_output}"
puts "End #{cmd_name}"

cmd_output
end
```